# Converting list to json in python , json.loads() error

Tags: python, json

after parsing of some java script callback, I have done trimming and got json-like object.
now I need to get some data from it and build new json with defined structure.

I have done this parsing with regexp
massive_string , You can find here : [CALLBACK](http://m.bananarepublic.gap.com/gmo/product?shopid=2&pid=950691012&region=us&callback=skone_callback&cid=5343&clientid=SKAVA)

```
Result = re.findall(r"\{\"catalogItemId\"\:.*\}", massive_string)
```

Result of trimming is **list** type and looks like:

```
['{"catalogItemId":"7549510","businessCatalogItemId":"950691","name":"Linen Full-Zip Sweater Jacket","catalogItemTypeId":"3","catalogItemSubtypeId":"13","isInStock":"true","inventoryStatusId":"0","sizeCategoryId":"0","defaultVariantId":"2","productStyleVariantList":[{"variantId":"1","variantName":"Regular","productStyleColors":[{"catalogItemId":"7549593"
 # ... some Stuff here ...
"hasAlternateImage":"false","hasCrossSell":"false","hasFitAttributeOverlayImages":"false","hasMergeVariants":"false","hasSplitVariants":"false","isGiftCard":"false","isImported":"true","careInstructionText":"Hand wash or dry clean.","flammableWarningText":"","marketingFlag":{"marketingFlagFormatId":"1","marketingFlagId":"102077","marketingFlagTypeId":"1","marketingFlagName":"Available in XS-XXL & Tall Online"},"onlyAvailableOnline":"false"},"localeInfo":{"supportedLocales":"en_US","responseLocale":"en_US"}}}']
```

so I need to do something like:

```
for i in Result:
    json.loads(i)
```

I'm getting:

```
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 21264 - line 1 column 21333 (char 21263 - 21332)
```

How can I find all needed `catalogItemId` and use their parameters for building personal JSON for each `catalogItemId` , and how I need to fix the `json.loads()` exception.

Comment: How did you get `Result` in the first place?

Comment: so basically your whole data is a list of one element with a string of all the contents?!

Comment: Without the actual data it is hard to do anything more that speculate; there are ways around the `Extra data` exception but it may not be a good idea to ignore that extra data. Most likely there are better ways to read your data in the first place.

Comment: what's the data around that mentioned in the error message? I guess there's an invalid character or extra quote or comma.

Comment: @zmo yes, but, type(Result) is <list>

Comment: @MartijnPieters I`ve updated question , answer to your ask is in the top of the question

Comment: @hago the result of parsing is huge, so I have no idea where must be that comma :(

Comment: @user3275828 since you iterate the Result, can you cature the exception within the loop and find the matches cause problem? something like for i in result: try: json.loads(i) except: ..., then add some string replace work before json.

Comment: @user3275828, most probably in position 21264

Comment: Just remove the `callback=` query parameter..

Comment: I think off topic close votes should be retracted, as this is quite a common problem. Though, we may find dupes of that Q...

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is actually by removing the `callback` argument of the url you're querying:

```
>>> import requests
>>> data = requests.get('http://m.bananarepublic.gap.com/gmo/product?shopid=2&pid=950691012&region=us&cid=5343&clientid=SKAVA').json()
>>>
```

that way, you don't have to do messy parsing of the JSON data. The callback argument is only an optional javascript trick to call an existing function that will parse the data upon reception of the JSON. As you'll see in the next example, I'm using the paramater `callback=foo` to change the name of the callback in the resulting json.

Ultimately, the problem is that you did not match just what was needed to remove the callback part of the string, but you tried to match data within the string:

```
>>> s = requests.get('http://m.bananarepublic.gap.com/gmo/product?shopid=2&pid=950691012&callback=foo&region=us&cid=5343&clientid=SKAVA').text
>>> s[0:60]
u'foo({"parentDivisionId":"5343","avgRating":0.0,"numRaters":0'
```

as a result, as you're using a greedy regex operator:

```
r"\{\"catalogItemId\"\:.*\}"
```

you're ending up parsing an uneven number of brackets within the string, that ultimately ends up being anything but JSON. Because it matches:

```
{"catalogItemId":foobar}
```

but also:

```
{"catalogItemId":"foobar"}, {"foo":"bar"}, {"foo":"bar"}},{"otherDataSet":{"catalogItemId":"barfoo"}}}}
^                                                                                                     ^
`----------------------- matching between those two brackets: ----------------------------------------`
```

which is not valid JSON. To understand how your regex works, please have a look at [this demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/dgUXm-SH76xA4kmY):

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You should have instead removed the callback, by using a substitution regex such as:

```
r"s/foo(\(.*\));/\1/"
```

for which the greedy operator will work as we want it to work: everything up to the last one.

Comment: `requests` response objects have a `.json()` method. No need to use the `json` module here.